# Store HTML form data in text file with new line

Tags: php

I am using below code to add information it a text file. I want each entry to be stored in a new line. Please check the code below and advise:

```
<?php
$txt = "test.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['Designation']) && isset($_POST['Deskphone']) && isset($_POST['staff'])) {
    $fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
    $txt=  $_POST['name'].' - '.$_POST['Designation'].' - '.$_POST['Deskphone'].' - '.$_POST['staff'].'-------'; 
    fwrite($fh,$txt); 
    fclose($fh); 
}
?>
```

Comment: Add a newline `\n` in double quotes.

Comment: @AbraCadaver Thanks I am New in PHP where should i Put /n ?

Comment: Add it to the end or beginning of $txt based on how you want it formatted.

Answer (score 2):

Add a newline/linefeed `\n` to the end.  Must be in double quotes.  See [PHP: Strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

```
$txt =  $_POST['name'].' - '
.$_POST['Designation'].' - '
.$_POST['Deskphone'].' - '
.$_POST['staff'].'-------'
."\n";
```

If you want to be able to see them on a newline in some Windows apps like notepad, then you must use `\r\n`.

For a cleaner one liner:

```
$txt = "{$_POST['name']} - {$_POST['Designation']} - {$_POST['Deskphone']} - {$_POST['staff']} -------\n";
```

Answer (score -2):

```
$txt = "test.txt"; 
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['Designation']) && isset($_POST['Deskphone']) && isset($_POST['staff'])) {
$fh = fopen($txt, 'a'); 
$txt=  $_POST['name'].'\n'.$_POST['Designation'].'\n'.$_POST['Deskphone'].'\n.$_POST['staff'].'-------'; 
fwrite($fh,$txt); 
fclose($fh);
```